# json_encode and mysql unicode problem

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, unicode

i have the following javascript code:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22561

Which works fine(the makewindows function has been changed to show it is a php variable), however the html contains unicode characters, and will only be assigned characters leading up to the first unicode character. If I make a small test file and echo out article_desc directly, all the html is output, although quetsions marks are displayed instead of the correct symbols. However json_encode seems to cut short the html, resulting in errors.

edit: here is a dump straight from the mysql database of the html I am trying to display:

http://www.yousendit.com/download/TTZueEVYQzMrV3hMWEE9PQ

it says utf-8 in the source. the actual page code generated from echoing out article_desc is here:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22566

it is definitely the same record, so I am unsure why it seems to very different.

edit: this was fixed by calling: mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

Comment: can you see if the unicode is correct in the database? i.e. are the question marks there or not?

Comment: From what I can tell there are no question marks in the database, but perhaps not correct unicode either.

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode` expects strings to be UTF-8 encoded byte streams. You'll have to either use utf-8 encoded strings internally (Which is the only current way to deal with unicode characters in PHP anyway), or use [a different library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html) for generating json.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the data or insert it into the mysql database as unicode?

Comment: You can convert latin1 strings (Which is the default for php5), using utf8_encode(). Why is it that you can't use Zend Framework components?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I am using **Zend_Db**/mysqli and my database content is actually UTF8.

I solved the problem by asking my database adapter to use UTF8:

```
$conf->db->params['charset'] = 'UTF8';
```

If you use PDO instead of mysqli, you can do it this way:

```
$pdoParams = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');
$conf->db->params['driver_options'] = $pdoParams;
```

If you don't use Zend_Db but use mysqli, you might want to look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php.

Source: http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/13

Answer (score 1):

```
json_encode( utf8_encode( $Content ) );
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think you need json_encode. json_encode encodes PHP arrays and objects to readable JavaScript format. If you send plain text or html within ajax you don't need json_encode

Comment: json_encode will also handle stuff like escaping quotes for you